# How to divide tableview into sections without changing the model

Tags: swift, tableview, sections

I am trying to add sections to my UITableView. I am able to create the sections and count the number of elements in each section properly, , the cells/images are repeated the data in all the sections.

Posting only relevant code:

Model:

```
struct Product:Equatable {
    let imagename: UIImage
}

var productarray = [
    Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "blue")),
    Product( imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CakeImage")),Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "vectorlogo")),
    Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PeasImge")),Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "castle")),
    Product( imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "scoobydoo")),Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ufo")),
    Product( imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "wolfsky")),Product( imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "universe")),
    Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "werewolf")),Product(  imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "galaxy"))
]
```

View Controller:

```
class ProductViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    let sections = ["Section A", "Section B","Section C", "Section D","Section E"]
    let rowspersection = [2,3,2,2,2]
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rowspersection[section]
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let data = productarray[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductTableViewCell") as! ProductTableViewCell
        cell.imageView?.image =  data.imagename
        cell.myParent = self
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        
        switch(section) {
        case 0: return "Section A"
        case 1: return "Section B"
        case 2: return "Section C"
        case 3: return "Section D"
        case 4: return "Section E"
        default: return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Result is:

[image]

Explaination:

The images in “productarray” in the model “struct Product” are:

`blue, CakeImage,  vectorlogo, PeasImge, castle,  scoobydoo , ufo, wolfsky, universe, werewolf, galaxy`

but the end-product in the simulator is:

Section A:  blue, CakeImage

Section B:  blue, CakeImage, vectorlogo

Section C:  blue, CakeImage

Section D:  blue, CakeImage

Section E:  blue, CakeImage

i.e. the images/cells are repeating, which I don’t want to happen. I want the sections to be placed between the cells/images as I wish. Please assist me.

what I want is:-

Section A:  blue, CakeImage

Section B:  vectorlogo, PeasImge, castle

Section C:  scoobydoo , ufo,

Section D:  wolfsky, universe

Section E:  werewolf, galaxy

Note: I don’t want to change the model "struct Product" because then I'll have to change other extensive code which I have not mentioned here.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, you don't want each section to repeat the previous items but continue displaying the items from the previous one?

Comment: @ItayBrenner - Please see edit

Comment: The problem is in the topic: *...without changing the model*. Do it, rather than *hard-coding* `numberOfRows` and `numberOfSections` create an suitable model.

Comment: Change the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem for you is that each section starts from row 0, and taking into account that you don't have a fixed number of rows per section, you will have to calculate how many position to advance in the array of products like this:

```swift
func getIndex(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
    var index = 0
    for i in 0..<indexPath.section {
        index += rowspersection[i]
    }

    index += indexPath.row
    
    return index
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = productarray[getIndex(indexPath: IndexPath)]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductTableViewCell") as! ProductTableViewCell
    cell.imageView?.image =  data.imagename
    cell.myParent = self
    
    return cell
}
```

A better solution is not to use an array for this but a dictionary mapped with sections like this:

Products:

```swift
var productMap = [
    0: [ Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "blue")), Product( imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CakeImage")) ]
    1: [ Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "vectorlogo")), Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PeasImge")), Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "castle"))],
    2: [ Product( imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "scoobydoo")),Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ufo"))] ,
    3: [ Product( imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "wolfsky")),Product( imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "universe")) ],
    4: [ Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "werewolf")),Product(  imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "galaxy")) ]
]
```

And in the VC:

```swift
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return productMap.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return productMap[section]?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = productMap[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductTableViewCell") as! ProductTableViewCell
    cell.imageView?.image =  data.imagename
    cell.myParent = self
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Your productMap works like a charm. You are such a blessing.